# Android: How to access Usage Statistics programmatically?

Tags: android, usage-statistics

*#*#4636#*#* display Information about

1) Phone

2) Battery

3) Usage Statistics

4) Wi-Fi

How can i access these stats programmatically? Is there any API available to access these statistics ?

Comment: "##4636## display Information" -- perhaps on your device it does. It does not do so on all devices. Please explain, in words or pictures, **completely and precisely** what stats you are trying to access.

Comment: I am not allowed to post an image now. 
I can explain it in words.

I want to find out that how many times user has open different apps installed on his device.
Also that how for how much time user has used different apps installed on his phone.
How can i do this?

Comment: "I am not allowed to post an image now" -- you can upload images elsewhere and link to them here. "How can i do this?" -- there are no public APIs in Android for this, and as far as I know Android itself does not track this information. If your device does track this information, please contact your device manufacturer for assistance in accessing it.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/k5jr62eb7/
http://postimg.org/image/5av5rw4qb/

Is this helpful? Though i understand what you are saying but did any thing came to your mind after seeing these images?

Comment: Hmmmm... it may be that those screens actually are part of AOSP. I see the `4636` code in [the Settings app's manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings.git/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml). I am not sure why that USSD code does not work on the Nexus 4, which is why I am assuming that exposing this capability via the USSD code may not be available on all devices. There's no public API for that information for that second screen, though. But you are certainly welcome to poke around the Settings app's source code to see what `TestingSettingsBroadcastReceiver` does.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go , but you should really try to look up stuff on your own
http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: Thank you but this is not what i am looking for. 
I want to get usage statistics as it is.

Comment: Then you need to write your own

Comment: But there should be a way to access these stats programmatically. System stores them at some place. I want to access that place.